# d3.js updating a pie chart

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I'm working a project for visualizing data a company is gathering, and using d3.js to show it. However, I can't wrap my head around it well, and am struggling to be able to update the charts. All the examples appear to be using .tsv files (?) or json files. This using things like d3.tsv.etc or similar patterned words.

I will be getting my information as a var in the javascript from an API. And need help setting up a function that will take that var as a parameter to update the graph. So far what I have is this:

```
var vis = d3.select("#graphs")
    .append("svg:svg")
    .data([data])
        .attr("width", w)
        .attr("height", h)
    .append("svg:g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + r + "," + (r + 50) + ")");
vis.append("text")
    .attr("x", 0)
    .attr("y", -(r + 10))
    .style("text-anchor", "middle")
    .text("Pages Visited");
var arc = d3.svg.arc()
    .outerRadius(r);
var pie = d3.layout.pie()
    .value(function (d) { return d.value; });
var arcs = vis.selectAll("g.slice")
    .data(pie)
    .enter()
          .append("svg:g")
            .attr("class", "slice");
arcs.append("svg:path")
        .attr("fill", function (d, i) { return color(i); })
        .attr("d", arc);
arcs.append("svg:text")
     .attr("transform", function (d) {
         d.innerRadius = 0;
         d.outerRadius = r;
         return "translate(" + arc.centroid(d) + ")";
     })
    .attr("fill", "white")
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    .text(function (d, i) { return data[i].label; });
```

And the data is currently just:

```
data = [{ "label": "Example 1", "value": 15 },
        { "label": "Example 2", "value": 65 },
        { "label": "Example 3", "value": 80 },
        { "label": "Example 4", "value": 40 }];
```

But that is to be replaced with an API call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This bit of your code creates the pie chart layout function:

```
var pie = d3.layout.pie()
  .value(function (d) { return d.value; });
```

In order to actually layout your data you should pass it to the function created:

```
var layedOutData = pie(data)
```

You can then pass this `layedOutData` to the `data` of your slice selection i.e.

```
var arcs = vis.selectAll("g.slice")
  .data(layedOutData)
```

In the `enter()` part of the code you add new slices and assign attributes to them based on the generated layout. If later on your data changes and you wish to update the slices (etc.) then you simply add the new data to the selection and update the attributes...

```
vis.selectAll("g.slice")
  .data(updatedLayedOutData)
  .select('svg:path')
  .attr('d',arc)
```

Comment: Thanks, but I still don't know how to update a pie chart. How do I write the function to alter the pie chart with the new layedOutData?

Comment: @RileyShaw I've extended the answer. I also notice that you're assignment to `var arcs` is the result of the the `enter()` call. It may be neater to do something like

```var arcs = vis.selectAll("g.slice")
    .data(pie)```

and then

```arc.enter().ADD_SOME_THINGS```

```arc.enter().SET_SOME_ATTRIBUTES```

Selections are one of the trickiest bits of D3 to get your head around but it's worth the effort. Mike Bostock's article on the subject is quite dense but worth taking time to understand... https://bost.ocks.org/mike/selection/
Hope that helps

Comment: What would you suggest to do for making it a smooth transition?

Comment: you can call `transition()` on your selection before setting attributes i.e. 
```arc.transition().SET_SOME_ATTRIBUTES```

Comment: This has been incredibly helpful, the only issue I have left is my second data set now has 5 fields. And when it updates, it resizes everything, but doesn't add a new path. (I tried appending and entering then appending and recreating my previous attempts but they error out saying they cant read j of undefined).